# Efficient way to manipulate DOM childs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, performance

My goal is to get a randomized shine effect on certain text using CSS `animation`.
I already have a working code, just want to know if there a more effective/simple solution.

HTML:

```
<span class="foo">
    <span class="bar">
    </span>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
@keyframes masked-animation {
    0% {background-position: -1000px 0}
    50% {background-position: 1000px 0}
    100% {background-position: 1000px 0}
}

.foo{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
}

.bar{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.67) 48%, rgba(255,255,255,0.9) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0.67) 52%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    animation-name: masked-animation;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    background-size: 400% 100%;
 }
```

JS:

```
$('.foo')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue = "Text";
$('.foo > .bar').css({
    "animation-duration" : 8 + Math.round(Math.random()*40)/10 + "s",
    "animation-delay" : Math.round(Math.random()*100)/10 + "s"
}).text("Text");
```

In order for the animation to look properly, it needs to be above the element/text. Having it on the same element will render it behind.
I tried using `::before` but I can't select it with JS since it doesn't actually exist in the DOM.

This needs to be applied to multiple elements and text inside `<span>` changes every so often.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5uvyu1xj/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative may be to create and directly manipulate a style sheet in javascript. In this way, iterating over the elements is handled by the browser rather than in javascript.

Setting up such a stylesheet is described in MDN's [CSSStyleSheet.insertRule()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule) examples.

There is also a [jQuery library](https://github.com/f0r4y312/jquery-stylesheet/) for these kind of manipulations.

And a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/ouroborus/t4jgecoL/):

```js
var styleElement = document.createElement('style');
document.head.appendChild(styleElement);

var styleSheet = styleElement.sheet,
    ruleIdx = styleSheet.insertRule('.target{}',styleSheet.cssRules.length),
    rule = styleSheet.cssRules[ruleIdx],
    colorize = function() {
        var color = Math.random() * 360;
        rule.style.color = 'hsl('+color+',100%,50%)';
    },
    interval = setInterval(colorize,1000);
colorize();
```

```html
<div class="target" style="font-size:5em;font-weight:bold;font-family:sans-serif">TEST</div>
```